# Implement zigzag flatten NxN tensor with batches in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

The problem can be described in [zigzag scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201395/zig-zag-scan-an-n-x-n-array). However, I wonder if there's is a TensorFlow version of implementation by using something like `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` that TensorFlow suggests.

BxNxN tensor where B represents Batch.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using 1x1 conv. Use numpy to generate a constant permutation conv kernel ( tf does not support eager tensor assignment... ), then
reshape tensor(BxNxN) to Bx1x1x(NxN) before applying `tf.nn.conv2d` to it. Finally do some reshape acrobat to flatten it.